# Как передать HTML в шорткод

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Есть такой шорткод `incutArticle`, в $content через админку втавляется html код с абзацами и ссылками. Шорткод возвращает обычный текст без замены html тегов.

Как можно написать, чтоб все, что написано в $content воспринималось как html при выводе на экран.

Вызов шорткода:

```
[incutArticle]<p><a href="#">Test</a></p>[/incutArticle]
```

Код шорткода:

```
add_shortcode( 'incutArticle', 'show_incutArticle' );
function show_incutArticle( $atts, $content, $tag ) {
    ob_start();
    ?>

    <div class="incutArticle"><?php echo esc_html( $content ); ?></div>


    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы код хтмл был кодом или вы хотите пользователю показать код?

Comment: чтобы был кодом, а сейчас все тэги отображается на сайте как текст

Comment: Тогда я вас правильно понял, ответ уже дал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`esc_html` - Заменяет спецсимволы на HTML сущности в переданном тексте, возвращает отформатированный текст. Заменяются следующие символы: &, <, >, ", '.

Используйте вместо нее `wp_kses` или ей подобные, например:

```
<div class="incutArticle"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $content ); ?></div>
```

https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_kses

https://wp-kama.ru/function/esc_html

Comment: работает, спасибо!